# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I get this exception sometimes only,like once in 100 calls. I looked for solutions but could not figure out. Stored procedure takes one input. The driver i use is sqljdbc4 version 4.0

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PROC_CATEGORY_LIST] @USERID INT
```

and i have set the parameter as follows

```
    "EXEC PROC_CATEGORY_LIST ?"
    callableStatement.setInt(1, userId);
    resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery();
```

I get the following exception

```
The value is not set for the parameter number 2.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 2.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.buildParamTypeDefinitions(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:260)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.buildPreparedStrings(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:219)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doPrepExec(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:612)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:400)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractQueryReport$StatementProxy.invoke(AbstractQueryReport.java:233)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
```

Has anyone faced such problem. If yes what could be the possible solution.

Comment: PROC_A_LIST != PROC_CATEGORY_LIST

Comment: The proc signature you are showing is `PROC_A_LIST` whereas you are calling `PROC_CATEGORY_LIST` - I'm guessing the latter has > 1 parameter?

Comment: sorry for this mistake. its PROC_CATEGORY_LIST not PROC_A_LIST.

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, can you remove the userId parameter and see what happens?

Comment: I removed userId and got this exception  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 1.

Comment: Did you find the cause of this issue. I faced a similar error.